# why I cant disable request validation?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I m supporting a MVC4 app and need to disable request validation for testing.

I have done the following in Web.config

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
<httpRuntime  requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

When I try to input html or script, it still validate the input and throws error ""

I dont have `[ValidateInput]`   with my actions, does `[ValidateInput]`   is there by default ?  I tried if I put `[ValidateInput(false)]`   it ignore validation.

Is there a way to make it ignoring validation without putting `[ValidateInput(false)]`  with actions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add that attribute to your global filter config but make sure it's only done in DEBUG mode only.
in your FilterConfig.cs, simply do

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    #if DEBUG
    filters.Add(new ValidateInputAttribute(false));
    #endif
}
```

Comment: great solution :)

Just to ensure, I can leave this code as it is even in production and it will only run if I am debugging. 
Also can I add other conditional code to work in production or staging and some bits just to work on local ?

Thanks

Comment: yes you can leave it even in PRODUCTION, anything in between the #if DEBUG lines is ignored when you build your solution using the Release configuration.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, what is thing is called I mean #if DEBUG
are there other spacifiers like DEBUG, just want to explore them momre.

Comment: [C# preprocessor directives (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)